# How to sum in google spreadsheet column by comparing some of the values in another column?

Tags: excel, sum, google-sheets

Say I have A, B, C, D, ...X, Y, Z in Column A. And I have numbers in column B as 10,20,30,40,50...for the corresponding A cells. I want to sum values of B where A is a vowel. How do I do it? I tried the 2 options below but that doesn't work

`=SUM(FILTER(B1:B26,((A1:A26="a") OR (A1:A26="e")OR (A1:A26="i") OR (A1:A26="o") OR (A1:A26="u"))))`

Also

`=SUMIF(A1:A26,"a"|"e"|"i"|"o"|"u",B1:B26)`

---

*For what they are worth, 'clarifications' from OP's comments*

**If the column had values like "Sunday", "Monday" .. and then we had to sum values corresponding to Weekdays.**

**If I had values like abc, deb, bcd, cde then it may fail when I want summation for bcd**

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((ISNUMBER(FIND(A1:A26,"aAeEiIoOuU")))*(B1:B26)))
```

for general case (when column `A` contains some word), use this one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((ISNUMBER(FIND("|" & A1:A26 & "|";"|a|A|e|E|i|I|o|O|u|U|")))*(B1:B26)))
```

change `"|a|A|e|E|i|I|o|O|u|U|"` to fit your requirements, e.g. `"|Sunday|Monday|"`

Comment: It may work in this case with single char but my Question was little more generic. For e.g. If the column had values like "Sunday", "Monday" .. and then we had to sum values corresponding to Weekdays.

Comment: It may work in this case with single char but my Question was little more generic. If I had values like _abc_, _deb_, _bcd_, _cde_ then it may fail when I want summation for _bcd_, _cde_ as it will find _bcd_ twice instead of once.

Comment: @JaiJwalaKi, see my updated answer for general case. BTW, you said that your column A contains single char and I found the solution.

Comment: @pnuts, let imagine that column `A` contains `aa`, `bb`, `a`, `AA`. It that case this part `"|" & A1:A26 & "|"` makes `|aa|`, `|bb|`, `|a|`, `|AA|`. This transform helps me to find exactly thouse values in, say, array `|aa|A|e|E|i|I|o|O|u|U|`. In that case `aa` will match, but `a` won't match. Sorry for bad explanation, but I hopes you'd understadn me. I've just tested it again - and it works. Or do you think something else worng with my formula?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work both in Excel and in New Google Sheets:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A26,{"a","e","I","o","u"},B1:B26))
```